# Trouble saving C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, save, loading

I am making an application for a 'Ski Resort' where you can add members and search members etc. So far I am having difficulty saving and loading these when the application closes. When I add a member, it saves, and then when I try to add another, the first member will not be saved anymore but the first one will have done.
Here is the code used to Save the members:

```
     public void Save(System.IO.TextWriter textOut)
    {
        textOut.WriteLine(number);
        textOut.WriteLine(name);
        textOut.WriteLine(address);
        textOut.WriteLine(score);
        textOut.Close();
    }

    public bool Save(string filename)
    {
        System.IO.TextWriter textOut = null;
        try
        {
            textOut = new System.IO.StreamWriter(filename);
            Save(textOut);
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (textOut != null)
            {
                textOut.Close();
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

The `StreamWriter` constructor you are using will overwrite the file each time. Use the constructor that also takes a boolean so you can make it append to the file. And you don't need the `TextWriter`.

```
try
{
   using(var textOut = new System.IO.StreamWriter(filename, true))
   {
       textOut.WriteLine("whatever..");
   }
}
```